# Using multiple modules in Android NDK

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk, makefile

I having trouble setting up my Android NDK based project with multiple modules which depend on each other.

What I would like to accomplish:

```
jni    
  Application.mk
  Android.mk          (includes make files from modules)
  app
    Android.mk        (needs libpng & libzip modules)
    JniModules.cpp
  libpng
    Android.mk
    ...               (more source files)
  libzip
    Android.mk
    ...               (more source files)
```

The JniModules.cpp file just include headers from libpng and libzip but the compiler can't seem find the libpng/png.h or libzip/zip.h files.

```
jni/app/JniModules.cpp:2:24: fatal error: libpng/png.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/JniModules/JniModules.o] Error 1
```

I've put a bare bones project on github: https://github.com/niob/JniModules.

Any pointers to how I should use another module from within a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your jni/app/android.mk, set LOCAL_C_INCLUDES
to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)`
or to ``LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/libpng`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348997/android-ndk-how-to-let-gcc-to-use-additional-include-directories)

Comment: I've already fixed it and idd the c_includes was missing! I gladly award you with the bounty for the effort. (you'll have to wait 3 hours though, SO doesn't allow me to give you the bounty yet) Txn