# Android Studio, OpenCV, C++, jni, NDK - unable to configure?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm attempting to get OpenCV C++ calls to work within Android Studio using jni & the Android Studio NDK.  These are the references I've been working from:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-2-mixedprocessing

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2014/10/22/android-ndk-and-opencv-development-with-android-studio/

https://blog.nishtahir.com/2015/11/11/setting-up-for-android-ndk-development/

http://kn-gloryo.github.io/Build_NDK_AndroidStudio_detail/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0vL7-_xuDM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmPuwdxR1qs

[Android NDK: how to let gcc to use additional include directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348997/android-ndk-how-to-let-gcc-to-use-additional-include-directories)

For the most part I've been attempting to get the 2nd OpenCV sample (first of the links above) to run within Android Studio.  This is the closest I have gotten so far:

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCVTestNative/tree/22895c5304c5fb7f0bd62c0f5eef494d3f0280f9

Currently I'm getting the error:

```
C:\Users\Chris.Dahms\Documents\AndroidOpenCVCppProgs\OpenCVTestNative\app\src\main\jni\jni_part.cpp
Error:(2, 28) opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I've tried everything in the above links to no avail.

I should mention that I can get the Java OpenCV calls to work within Android Studio, essentially following this post:

[OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

But no matter what I have done I have not been able to get the C++ jni calls to work.  I made the above-linked GitHub project by starting with the project wizard, then adding parts from the 2nd OpenCV for Android sample:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-2-mixedprocessing

The other way I've tried it is downloading the OpenCV source from:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv

Then unzipping and using the Android Studio "Import Project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)" Option.  After import I get the message

[image]

I've read up on the experimental plugin and that does not seem to be the recommended way to go, so I choose the

```
Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration
```

Option, which puts the line:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

At the end of gradle.properties.  After that I get many errors, however if I follow the steps from

[OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)

again, that gets me back to the same

```
Error:(2, 28) opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
```

here is what my screen looks like:

[image]

Here is the project if it would be helpful to look at the source:

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/tutorial-2-mixedprocessing

Has anybody actually gotten this to work?  I've seen some posts implying it's possible but I can't find any concrete instructions.  Can anybody who has had some success with this please share with the rest of us ??

Edit:
It has been suggested that this is an answer:

[Android Studio with opencv for android ndk, opencv header files not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214015/android-studio-with-opencv-for-android-ndk-opencv-header-files-not-found)

While this did get me past the opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory error, in Android Studio the FindFeatures call still appears red as though the Java file can't see the C++ file:

[image]

And in the app's build.gradle file, multiple lines have underline errors:

[image]

[image]

Any further suggestions??

Further edit:

I forgot to mention that I get the underline errors in build.gradle with the additions outside the default bracket as well:

[image]

And when I run the app it crashes with the error

```
couldn't find "libmixed_sample.so"
```

in LogCat and on the phone gives the "unfortunately the app has stopped" error

Any further suggestions?

Comment: contents of Android.mk file would be helpful as the problem related to c++ code is not able to figure out where core.hpp present

Comment: Here is the first of the two from my attempts linked above:

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCVTestNative/blob/master/jni/Android.mk

and here is the 2nd of the two:

https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/tutorial-2-mixedprocessing/blob/master/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk

I should mention that I've tried putting the jni directory at the (root of the project), (root of the project)/app, and (root of the project)/app/src/main, same error show above in all cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio with opencv for android ndk, opencv header files not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214015/android-studio-with-opencv-for-android-ndk-opencv-header-files-not-found)

Comment: Nicely defined set of attempts.  Any progress?

Comment: No, and unfortunately it looks like this is a known issue within the OpenCV organization that may not be resolved for some time, check out this post: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5003  When I get back to this I'm going to give the Java function calls a thorough try.  Since they wrap the OpenCV libs, which are true compiles, I'm hoping the performance loss will be negligible if any at all.

Comment: @cdahms Did it work for you? I am asking the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551292)