# Unable to find mixed_sample.so

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, opencv3.0

I'm trying to build tutorial-2-mixedprocess application (in android-studio) that came with the opencv-SDK 3.2.0. But my application crashes because of a missing **mixed_sample** library

```
// Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");     //This one is taken care in CmakeLists.txt
Log.d(TAG, "Loaded the opencv");        //This line appears on the monitor                        
System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");   // C-R-A-S-H h h h
```

I looked inside **OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs** directory that came with opencv-3.2.0-android-sdk.zip but *mixed_sample.so is nowhere to be found.

Where to find this file?

EDIT
The full error says following:
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.opencv.samples.tutorial2-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmixed_sample.so"`

Comment: do you have .so files in zip ?

Comment: yes, there are 17 files in total. None is named libmixed_sample.so.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio do the following

1. Create Folder "jniLibs" inside "src/main/"
2. Put all your .so libraries inside "src/main/jniLibs" folder
3. just sync gradle again and project. Run your application.

make sure you have put java and jnilibs at proper places.

can you share tree structure of project screenshot?

Comment: Its all there. In the first line of the code snippet I am loading opencv  `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");` and it works as the relevant `.so` file is there inside the jniLibs. [Here is the tree structure](https://pasteboard.co/iHTyq7TR5.png).